# PRs with me as requested reviewer doesn't show up in my GitHub PR lis

Tags: github, pull-request

This has bugged me for a long time. I'm part of an organization with many private repos, and I regularly get requests to review PRs in those repos. But these PRs never show up in my global GitHub PR list at https://github.com/pulls/review-requested . Something must be wrong?

[image: global PR list]

[image: example of open PR]